# What would make my gravity increase?

Tags: gravity-reading, cider, troubleshooting

I have a cider that i have been fermenting for almost two weeks.  I took a reading about four days ago and it was 1.005, we decided it was about time to bottle.  Then last night when we got around to bottling i took another reading and it was 1.018!  This is before i added the priming sugar.  I cant figure out what would have made the gravity go back up after getting down to 1.005?

Answer (score 5):

Unless you added sugar or evaporated water, a misreading is the only answer I can come up with. Always make sure to spin your hydrometer to ensure there are no air bubbles forcing it up higher.

Any chance your dog knocked in a pound of DME? :)

Answer (score 2):

Most likely user error with a small difference possible due to temperature and/or dissolved co2 floating the hydrometer. It's also possible that there is a density gradient, though it seems less likely after 2 weeks of fermenting.